# What does it means in the dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

I keep using this dictionary but I don't know what does it means. The first one I know is the gender and the last one is the plural form but how about the middle one.

https://de.thefreedictionary.com/plan

> -(e)s

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Read the answer to the linked question to learn details. Here the short answer: Nominativ singular: »der Plan«. Genitiv singular: »des Planes« or »des Plans« (two different genitive forms). Nominativ plural: »die Pläne« (The dot in the word marks syllable borders).

Comment: Practically, it shouldn’t make a difference for this question, but the other question is in German, so we do not technically consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The part behind the article is the genitive ending as already commented.

> »Was fällt dir zu Politik ein?«
>   »Verarschung ist Teil des Plan[e]s.«

The optional »e« is rarely used.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Was hat dich zur Änderung von »Verarschung« zu »Verbesserung« bewogen?

Comment: Es klingt einfach netter ;-)

Comment: Was hat Dich denn zur Rückänderung bewogen, bzw. warum verwendest Du in dem Kontext _"Verarschung"_?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Das ist doch nur ein Beispielsatz, der mit nichts außerhalb des Beispiels zu tun hat, ich will damit nichts kommentiert haben, was mit der Frage zu tun hat.

Comment: Es hat halt ein "Gschmäckle", deshalb hatte ich es editiert.